# Copy Chart & Print Very Slow VBA

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a performance problem and google doesn't help me.
This person has the same problem :
http://excel.bigresource.com/Copy-Chart-Print-Very-Slow-1eeSa883.html

When I copy an excel chart with VBA : This is so slooooow.

```
  Dim myChart As ChartObject
    For Each myChart In consoPDC.ChartObjects
        myChart.Copy
        ...
    Next
```

Any idea that makes it faster ?
For information the objective is to paste them in powerpoint.

The weird thing is that making it manually isn't slow at all

Thanks.
Nico.

Comment: Can you please mention the Excel version? Also if you can post the complete code that you are using? I can test it for you?

Comment: Excel 2003. No need to add any more vba code, the only line struggling  is the myChart.copy I can even feel it while debugging.

Comment: Is the copying slower or the pasting? The reason, I ask is because I tested it and it works just fine for me...

Comment: Only copying is very slow. Like 5 to 10 seconds. The chart is by the way an histogram built by data computed with a very large amount of formulas. Maybe excel is recalculating the data while copying ? This would be awful. I will try to enable manual calculation before copying.

Comment: I just removed autocalculation and the problem is still there. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are making a copy into PowerPoint, i'll suggest you to try out this code:

```
myChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
```

found this in MS-Help and [here](http://www.office-loesung.de/ftopic530015_0_0_asc.php&sid=d36eb45190414fb290626179987c7034)

also found a nice hint [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/chartobject-copy-very-slow-t3475789.html), according to, the following code should be faster

```
myChart.ChartArea.Copy
```

Testet on a small scale demo, excited to hear about big scale results :) would be nice to have some comparision in seconds, when you try this out.

**edit:** just another thing to watch out for - memory leaks

if you do extensive copy to clipboard you should watch out to clean up afterwards, otherwise you might fill up your memory quite fast ;) this could also result in weak performance, as many systems might move data to the pagefile, slowing access down.

**edit:** just if you should be into the last bit of a second and if you have many charts to copy

using `For each` is slower than to iterate through your objects with a neat loop. However, the code does not look that neat like using `for each`, but if any sec/millisec counts one should compare them against each other.

I found this in a specialized Book of Micheal Schwimmer, tested it and was suprised. Not sure anymore in which circumstances, but tested it on a bigger scale and confirmed.

Comment: How would you suggest to clean up after copying to clipboard to not run into memory problems?